# Symfony, Move data from em1 to em2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I use Symfony 2.8.

I have a huge table with a lot of datsa i don't need anymore. I want to move datas in another database with a symfony command.

I have 2 entities managers:

em_archive = mydb_archive

em_default = mydb

I have the code:

```
    $emDefault = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager('em_default');
    $emArchive = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager('em_archive');
    $repoArchive = $emDefault->getRepository('MyBundle\Datas', 'em_archive');
    $repoDefault = $emDefault->getRepository('MyBundle\Datas', 'em_default');

    $dataTest = $repoDefault->getOneDataTest();
    $dataTest->setOldId($dataTest->getId());
    $dataTest->setId(null);
    $emArchive->persist($dataTest);
    $emArchive->flush();
```

With the code i have the error "Notice: Undefined index: 000000004618b9830000000172fdd8f3"

Is there a problem with one of my entity links (onetomany, manytoone) ?

Comment: can you try adding $emDefault ->detach($dataTest) just before setting the ids?

Comment: And please note that the entity manager is not designed to do massive import/export, you should use DBAL connection for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entities are mapped to an Entity Manager by the class type, so you cannot have the same class mapped into two entity manager. This is by design, as you can see from proxy classes, which contains references to the `UnitOfWork` and/or to the owning `EntityManager`.

Also, the performance of load-hydrate-persist-dehydrate-flush is very poor, you get lot of memory leak issues, and so on.

So, you can't use the ORM layer, but you can still use Doctrine DBAL.

See [DBAL insert](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#insert) for an example of "mapping" syntax, or use good old-fashioned queries.